# Is it possible to reboot a remote computer, which isn't in a local network/ Domain and not enlisted in AD?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, remote-access, reboot

I got this assignment where my assignment is to reboot a remote computer which isn't in any AD nor on my local network/ Domain.

Currently I am capable of checking whether or not the IP-address and port is active. What I want is to be able to call a shutdown function directly on the remote computer. However it appears as if most of the solutions on the web, which I'm capable of finding, isn't working when the computer isn't in your local network or domain.

Here's the current code used:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CPMSMonitor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestConnection();


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static IEnumerable<String> GetConfig()
        {

            var list = new List<String>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var settingValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[$"PC{i}"];
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(settingValue))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(settingValue);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

        private static HttpClient BuildHttpClient(string endPoint)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://" + endPoint) };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return client;
        }

        static void TestConnection()
        {
            var timer = 1000;

            if (!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("IntervalTimer"), out timer))
            {
                timer = 1000;
            }

            var machines = GetConfig();
            var client = BuildHttpClient(machines.First());

            while (true)
            {

                foreach (var item in machines)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://" + item);

                        var httpResponse = client.GetAsync("/").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        var html = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                        Console.WriteLine(item + " | Status: Online");
                    }
                    catch {

                        Process.Start("Shutdown.exe", "-r");
                        // use PsShutdown to reboot machine
                        // call to IP failed
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(timer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7"/>
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PC1" value="192.168.195.65:8080"/>
    <add key="PC2" value="192.168.195.65:8081"/>
    <add key="IntervalTimer" value="500"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Do you guys have any idea how to call a system function in which the administrative access is granted and the computer afterwards reboots? 
PsShutdown, PsExec and even Azure apps has been attempted, though failing.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "in which the administrative access is granted"? You can't reboot a machine if you don't have administrative access. Do you have credentials of an administrator you could use to log in to the machine or not? If not, your options are going to be limited to finding a software vulnerability to escalate privilege or cause a hard crash... which is not exactly elegant even if it was possible.

Comment: So what your saying is that you want a command that allows you to shutdown any PC even if you don't have access to it over a network?

Comment: You're going to need some sort of admin access one way or another. Either admin access directly to the computer, or you'll need someone with admin access to install a program on the machine that your application can communicate with to send a reboot command.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else but personally I'm quite glad you can't shut down my computer remotely without me having granted you prior permission.

Comment: Are you allowed to locally install some sort of program on the computer which you then could send a message to which will initiate the shutdown process?

Comment: Hey guys, 

So yea - I kind of feel the same way about the whole Administrative access. I was simply wondering whether or not this would be possible, without direct access. 
The idea I think we're going with is to install a local script on each computer that loops, and then reboots the computer if needed, since we're not going to go through the administrative work to set up AD on those computers. 

But thanks though, was just wondering if there was some sort of coding "backdoor" in which you could active the reboot, without manually accessing each pc :-)

Comment: If there was, then it would be a massive gaping security hole and MS would be getting serious heat if it was known about. And then a patch would appear almost instantly. It would be big news if you could go round shutting down machines remotely without gaining prior permission.